# Grids in box bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to bulid grids like the photo below

IMG LINK: http://postimg.org/image/qo3b4nof1/

But i'm getting the **DIV E** in almost next to the D-DIV

here's my code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="col-md-1">A</div><br/>
            <div class="col-md-1">B</div><br/>
            <div class="col-md-1">C</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">D<br/>
            <div class="col-md-1">E</div>       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The break-lines i added because DIV-A and DIV-B become one piece without breaklines.

is it better to do it with table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use container and row with bootstrap 3.*

I changed you code to match the provided screenshot, see this http://jsfiddle.net/Sd2zw/ .
I just use xs columns because the small screen of jsfiddle, you can replace it back by md :

```
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <div class="col-xs-12">A</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">B</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">C</div>  
            <span class="clearfix"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <div class="col-xs-12 d-container">D</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-1">E</div>  
                <span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <span class="clearfix"></span>
    </div>
```

Also,  use some clearfix tags to clear the float.

Comment: Thanks Alot,
I've several blocks in my website. 
Container to have padding from left and right.

Comment: Or you can do it like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd2zw/1/) according to the bootstrap [nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting).